# Cannot index array with string "xxx"

Tags: jq

I have a json file as this,

```
# cat input.json
{
  "foo":[
     "key1",
     "key2"
   ],
  "bar": "key3"

}
```

And I want to join all those strings ("key1", "key2", key3") into one string, and I define the filter as this,

```sh
# cat filter.jq
[.[] | . as { foo: $names,  bar: $name} | {
    name1: [ $names | range(0;length) as $i | {
        key1: ($names[$i])
    }],
    name2: {
        key2: $name
    }
  } | {
    values: (.name1 | map(.key1) | join(" ") + .name2.key2)
}]
```

But this doesn't work,

```
# <input.json jq  --slurp --from-file filter.jq > output.json
jq: error (at <stdin>:8): Cannot index array with string "name2"
```

What's wrong going here?

btw. concat with a string seems works.

```
values: (.name1 | map(.key1) | join(" ") + "key3")
```

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Seems like `{ "values": to_entries | map(.value) | flatten | join(" ") }` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is underspecified, but you might wish to consider:

```
[.. | strings] | join(" ")
```

or similar.